# UISplitViewController - only shows half of UIViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

My `UISplitViewController` is only showing a half of the `UIViewController`

See picture:

[image]

This is my `appdelegate.m`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
    splitViewController.delegate = splitViewController.viewControllers.lastObject;
    return YES;
}
```

And here you can see my storyboard:

[image]

How do i fix this?

**Update**

`DetailViewContainerController.m`

```
-(void)mineSygedomme:(int)viewId {
UIViewController *viewController;
switch (viewId) {
    case 0:
        viewController = self.vaccinationer;
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
        break;
    case 1:
        viewController = self.skadestuen;
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
        break;
    case 2:
        viewController = self.leagen;
        [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:NO];
        break;
}
[self showChildViewController:viewController];
}

-(void)showChildViewController:(UIViewController*)content {
if(topController != content) {
    content.view.frame = [self.view frame];
    [self.view addSubview:content.view];
    [content didMoveToParentViewController:self];
    topController = content;
}
}
```

`LeftMenuviewcontroller.m`

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
[self.splitViewController setDelegate:self];

self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
self.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(300.0, 600.0);
[super awakeFromNib];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
self.detailViewContainerController = (DetailViewContainerController *)[self.splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
}
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

DetailViewContainerController *test2 = [[self.splitViewController.viewControllers.lastObject childViewControllers] objectAtIndex:0];
//    test2.detailViewContainerController = self;
test2.forNavn = [arrayA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSLog(@"test3 = %@",test2.forNavn);

if ([[[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] valueForKey:@"gender"]isEqualToString:@"Pige"]) {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main-iPad" bundle:nil];
    DetailViewContainerController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuPige"];
    controller.forNavn = [arrayA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSLog(@"pige = %@", controller.forNavn);
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

}
if ([[[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath] valueForKey:@"gender"]isEqualToString:@"Dreng"]) {
    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main-iPad" bundle:nil];
    DetailViewContainerController *controller = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuDreng"];
    controller.forNavn = [arrayA objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"dreng = %@", controller.forNavn);

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

}
}
```